# How call two functions one after another onClick in reactjs. Both functions are async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks

*How can I call two functions onClick one after another*

My code is as follows:

```js
import React from "react";

import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const DeleteModal = ({
  show,
  handleClose,
  deleteModalData: { type, id },
  deleteFn,
  loading,
  dishData,
  setDishData,
}) => {
  const removeIngredient = async () => {
    let restIngredients = dishData.ingredients.filter(
      (ingredient) => ingredient.ingredient_id !== id
    );

    setDishData({ ...dishData, ingredients: [...restIngredients] });
  };

  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Delete {type}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this {type}?</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          No
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            removeIngredient();
            deleteFn();
          }}
          disabled={loading}
        >
          Yes {loading ? "..." : null}
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default DeleteModal;
```

in the parent component of the above component I have defined the props  deleteFn and setDishData as follows:

**deleteFn**

```js
  
  const deleteFn = () => {
    saveIngredients();
  };

  const filteredIngredientData = () =>
    /**
     * filteredIngredientData - filters out the fields (from ingredients object) that are required by the API
     */
    ingredients
      ?.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return [
          acc,
          {
            ingredient_quantity: val.ingredient_quantity,
            ingredient_id: val.ingredient_id,
            is_required: val.is_required,
          },
        ];
      }, [])
      .flat(Infinity);

  const [loadingSaveIngredients, setLoadingSaveIngredients] = useState(false);
  const [ingredientsUpdated, setIngredientsUpdated] = useState(false);

  const saveIngredients = () => {
    /**
     * saveIngredients - Upload ingredients with updated quantities if any
     */
    setLoadingSaveIngredients(true);
    axios({
      method: "PUT",
      url: `${BASE_URL}/dishes/${props.match.params.id}/ingredients`,
      data: { ingredients: filteredIngredientData() },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setLoadingSaveIngredients(false);
        setShowDeleteModal(false);
        setIngredientsUpdated(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

**setDishData**

```js
const [dishData, setDishData] = useState({});
```

I have tried to use promise too, but no luck. Is there any simple way to do this?

*I know that I have to use async await somehow, but I am unable to understand how should I use it. Any help will be appreciated :)*

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

So I think I implemented it wrong; insead:

1. when you call setDishData also call toggleRemoved to indicate its been called within removeIngredients (if this is the only place setDishData is called then you don't need to implement removed/toggleRemoved)
2. then call deleteFn in a useEffect where dishData is the dependency;
   since deleteFn is dependent on setDishData, and setDishData changes dishData, the useEffect will be triggered after changes complete.
3. in deleteFn add a conditional that checks if removed is true (this again is only necessary if setDishData is also called from other functions, as you don't want those functions to trigger saveIngredients i within the deleteFn function).

```
const [dishData, setDishData] = useState(0);
const [removed, toggleRemoved] = useState(false);

const removeIngredients = () => {
   let restIngredients = dishData.ingredients.filter(
      (ingredient) => ingredient.ingredient_id !== id
    );

    setDishData({ ...dishData, ingredients: [...restIngredients] });
    toggleRemoved(true); 
}

useEffect(() => {
     deleteFn(); 
}, [dishData]);
```

```
<button onClick={removeIngredients}>
```

```
const deleteFn = () => {
    if(removed){
     saveIngredients();
     toggleRemoved(false); 
    }
 };
```

Comment: Great try, but this still doesn't fit my usecase

Comment: I think I implemented it wrong and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from "react";
    
    import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    const DeleteModal = ({
      show,
      handleClose,
      deleteModalData: { type, id },
      deleteFn,
      loading,
      dishData,
      setDishData,
    }) => {
      const removeIngredient = async () => {
        let restIngredients = dishData.ingredients.filter(
          (ingredient) => ingredient.ingredient_id !== id
        );
    
        setDishData({ ...dishData, ingredients: [...restIngredients] });
      };
    
//new function
 function myFun(){
    removeIngredient();
    dFun();          
}
function dFun(){
    deleteFn();
}
      return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Delete {type}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this {type}?</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              No
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="primary"
              onClick={() => myFun()}
              disabled={loading}
            >
              Yes {loading ? "..." : null}
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      );
    };
    
    export default DeleteModal;
```